# Why can't you use 'this' in member initializers?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use ‘this’ in member initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023640/cannot-use-this-in-member-initializer)

Any ideas why I get an error if I try to do something like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private Bar _bar = new Bar(this);
}
```

I get an error saying:

"Cannot use 'this' in member initializer"

but the following works:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Bar _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = new Bar(this);
    }
}
```

Anyone know the reason behind this? My understanding was that these would compile to the same IL, so am curious as to why one is allowed and the other isn't.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is closed as a duplicate, as the answer to the other question is about why it wasn't being reported as an error was answered with "this is a bug in the compiler" without actually explaining why it wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I *suspect* it's to prevent you from using the object before *at least* the base class constructor has run, ensuring that all the base class members are appropriately initialized. (Variable initializers are executed *before* the base class constructor, whereas the constructor body is executed *after* that.)

Will check whether the annotated spec has anything to say about this when I'm next near it...

EDIT: The C# 4 annotated spec doesn't have any explanation. Just (in 10.5.5.2):

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Never realized that variable initializers ran before the base class ctor...

Comment: You are of course correct. We should add that to the next edition of the annotated spec, that's a good one.

Comment: There goes VS suggestion of converting my backing fields to `Lazy`

Answer (score 15):

Field initializers run before base class constructors so `this` doesn't yet exist. It exists only once the base constructor has finished executing.

[17.10.2 Instance variable initializers](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/17.10.2.htm):

> When an instance constructor has no
>   constructor initializer, or it has a
>   constructor initializer of the form
>   base(...), that constructor implicitly
>   performs the initializations specified
>   by the variable-initializers of the
>   instance fields declared in its class.
>   This corresponds to a sequence of
>   assignments that are executed
>   immediately upon entry to the
>   constructor and before the implicit
>   invocation of the direct base class
>   constructor. The variable
>   initializers are executed in the
>   textual order in which they appear in
>   the class declaration.

Comment: Well it exists - it just isn't fully initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because fields initialize before the class initializes so when the following code is run:

```
private Bar _bar = new Bar(this);
```

"this" has no actual value to be referenced.

While putting it in the constructor means that there is an instance of "Foo" referencable by "this"

Answer (score 0):

In C#, no logic is intended to be outside methods' and properties' bodies.

Field initializers are an exception, but with some limitations.

It'd wrong getting a reference of current object with **this** keyword because a class field declaration isn't logic but class design, while **this** is part of run-time semantics.

By the way, it seems it's a C# design decision, <strike>because, in fact, a field initializer runs during class construction, so "current instance of declaring class" should be available through **this**. But again, what would be **this** outside a method or property body scope?</strike>

As Jon Skeet and others pointed, **this** isn't available because field initializers are executed after base constructor execution.

Comment: Outside a method or property body, it would still be the object in whose context the code was executing. It would make perfect *sense* to allow this for member initializers - it would just have issues if it tried to use state which hadn't been initialized by the base class yet.

Comment: Absolutely agreed and thank you for the comment. That's why I point to the fact that this is a C# design decision, but I ask the question because I find confusing having **this** keyword in this scope (it can easly be a whole of errors).

Comment: ías: But note that with the *small* change to C# to make it act more like Java (where the superclass constructor is executed before the variable initializers) that cause of errors would go away. I think *fundamentally* it makes sense - it's just that there are some caveats.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Agreed and thanks for the info. In fact (and in my case), field initializers are avoided in my code. And, in instance, I only initialize fields when I want to set read-only ones. I prefer to stay away from them. For setting private fields I use property setters.

Answer (score 0):

Member initializers run before class constructor. Consider that you might have many member initializers in a single class.

If you use 'this' in constructor -> all members with initializers were initialized. So everything is OK.

If you use 'this' in member initializer: other members (with initializers attached) might not be initialized yet -> 'this' is not yet ready. That is why using 'this' is not allowed here is not allowed.