# Is it possible in C# for an object to pass a reference to itself to the constructor of a child object it creates in it's own base constructor?

Tags: c#

So, lets say I have the following objects:

```
public abstract class Chicken
{
    public Egg Container { get; private set; }

    protected Chicken(Egg container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }
}

public abstract class Egg
{
    public Chicken Contents { get; private set; }

    protected Egg(Chicken contents)
    {
        Contents = contents;
    }
}

public class Buckeye : Chicken
{
    public Buckeye(Egg container) : base(container)
    {

    }
}

public class BrownEgg : Egg
{
    public BrownEgg() : base(new Buckeye(this))
    {

    }
}
```

Thank you to Wikipedia for supplying the name of a chicken breed.

Anyway, the previous code won't compile. It will tell you "Cannot use 'this' in member initializer."

So, I want to know if there is a way this can be done. Can you pass a reference to the object being constructed, to a child object that is also being constructed, that needs to be passed to the outer objects base?

I probably worded the question title poorly, but it's a difficult concept to communicate succinctly.

Comment: That barely makes any sense. You can make a private constructor that doesn't take the other object, and make a static factory method using this private constructor, I guess.

Comment: The idea is simply to allow the egg to know it's contents and the chicken to know it's container.

Comment: @Telarian - You need to do two-stage initialization. Consider how C# winforms does things - you construct a container, construct a containee, and then add the containee to the container.

Comment: Can you pass this to the base class constructor if you first cast it to the base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `this` in call to base constructor (see [Why can't you use 'this' in member initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125247/why-cant-you-use-this-in-member-initializers)).

You can pass creator function instead of populated object to let inner constructor to pass `this`. Something like:

```
protected Egg(Func<Egg, Chicken> contentsCreator) 
{
   Contents = contentsCreator(this);
}

public BrownEgg() : base(me => new Buckeye(me))
{
}
```

Comment: That is a very interesting possibility. Brilliant perhaps. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Telarian Just make sure you head does not explode when you try to read such code in a month :)

Comment: heh, ya, some extensive comments may be in order

Comment: @Telarian I don't see why in my suggestion base class (Egg) needs to know anything about derived one... `Func<Egg, IChicken>`? (or maybe I misunderstood your comment).

Comment: Actually, I was just misunderstanding my own translation of pseudo to real code. It works perfectly. A bit confusing yes, but comments can handle that. Thank you for the fine idea.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, and here's why: the base constructor fires before your more derived constructor, but the base constructor would act upon `this` being your more derived class... Which isn't done being constructed because it's waiting for the base constructor to finish before firing your derived constructor. Not sure if that makes a lot of sense how I wrote it but basically you can't pass an unconstructed class to a base class.

Comment: So the derived type will have to handle it itself I guess. Unfortunately I don't see any way to ensure that it does...

Comment: Actually right now it couldn't even if it wanted to since the Contents setter is private...

Comment: As I said. The goal is simply to let them know each other. Obviously this is all pseudo for something more complex.

Comment: Create a container class that takes as a constructor a `Chicken` and `Egg` and can facilitate communication between them perhaps?