# "this" is unavailable when directly initializing class member variable

Tags: c#, initialization, this

Why does the compiler give an error about this being unavailable that  when initializing an instance variable when defining it?

> Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

The constructor initialization is fine. I understand the scenario here - I just wanted to find the reason (via MSDN or otherwise) why "this" is available to a constructor but not directly if initializing the member variable.

Here is a simple abstraction of the error I'm seeing.

```
public class ClassA
{
    // Gets compiler error that "this" unavailable
    protected ClassB _a1 = new ClassB(this);

    // Works fine
    protected ClassB _a2;
    public ClassA() { _a2 = new ClassB(this); }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassA A { get; private set; }
    public ClassB(ClassA a) { this.A = a; } 
}
```

I was hoping to keep my initialization next to the assignment since the above example is an abstraction of my code where I am defining Lazy valueFactory delegates for 10-15 member variables in which the delegates need the data context passed as a parameter to the constructor. With 15 member variables, I'd prefer to keep the assignment next to the definition on a single line instead of having 15 lines of definitions and then another 15 lines in the constructor initializing each one.

This is basically what I had to do in my actual code:

```
public class MyContext
{
    public ProgramService Programs { get { return _programs.Value; } }
    protected Lazy<ProgramService> _programs;

    public MyContext()
    {
        _programs = new Lazy<ProgramService>(() => new ProgramService(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the fields to be initialzed before the constructor gets hit

Comment: Here's pretty good answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125247/why-cant-you-use-this-in-member-initializers

Comment: Although now that I look at it, the question michalk references is probably more accurate.

Comment: @michalk - Looks like Jon Skeet's answer is exactly why - no reason specified in annotated C# specs, just that it is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically to keep you from relying on the order ([textual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa645759(v=VS.71).aspx)) and possibly non-usable state of the class under construction. I think the overriding principle at stake is that if it's "complicated" logic, then you should be using a constructor.

Eg., doing this:

```
class A {
   private int x = 1;
   private int y = this.x + 1;
}
```

would lead to different results than:

```
class A {
   private int y = this.x + 1;
   private int x = 1;
}
```

which is a little unexpected. To side-step the issue, but still allow the convenience of inline init - disallowing `this` makes the ordering not matter.

In your actual code, you could possibly do a lazy check to keep things located together:

```
public ProgramService Programs { 
   get { 
      if (_programs == null) _programs = new ProgramService(this);
      return _programs.Value; 
   } 
}
// change this to private to keep subclasses from accessing a possibly null reference
private Lazy<ProgramService> _programs;
```

Comment: You imply that the initialization is done top-down. Is that actually defined somewhere?

Comment: @Ralf - link added to spec ("variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration")

Comment: One additional thing of note: instance fields are initialized as soon as any of the constructors are called... which implies it happens before any calls to a super class's constructor.