# Initialize objects in Blazor component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

With this Blazor component:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @_a.CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@_b.IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@functions {
    private readonly ClassA _a = new ClassA();
    private readonly ClassB _b = new ClassB(_a);

    class ClassA
    {
        public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassB
    {
        private readonly ClassA _classA;

        public ClassB(ClassA classA)
        {
            _classA = classA;
        }

        public void IncrementCount() => _classA.CurrentCount++;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property '__Counter._a'

This thread explain how resolve this error in standard class:

[Why can't you use 'this' in member initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125247/why-cant-you-use-this-in-member-initializers)

But for this, it needs a constructor.

Is it possible to add constructor in Blazor component?

How resolve this error?

Comment: You proably have to use the [OnInit](https://github.com/software-architects/learn-blazor/blob/master/content/pages/lifecycle-methods.md) method.

Comment: This done the job, but I need remove the readonly attribut to initialize _a and _b in OnInit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, `init` also was my first idea and, after read OP comment, I guess "code-behind" is the only way to match readonly properties requirement. I elaborate an answer with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep classes readonly you should to move to ["code-behind"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#base-class-inheritance-for-a-code-behind-experience). Then you can instantiate classes on constructor:

```
@page "/counter"
@inherits CounterBase
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @_a.CurrentCount ...
```

**`CounterBase.cs`**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Components;

namespace YourApp.Pages
{

    public class ClassA
    {
        public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        private readonly ClassA _classA;

        public ClassB(ClassA classA)
        {
            _classA = classA;
        }

        public void IncrementCount() => _classA.CurrentCount++;
    }

    public class CounterBase : BlazorComponent
    {
        protected readonly ClassA _a;
        protected readonly ClassB _b;

        //constructor
        public CounterBase()
        {
            _a = new ClassA();
            _b = new ClassB(_a);
        }
        ...
```

Comment: The constructor is invalid. Can you remove the void? And I valid you answer.

Comment: lel, of course. Sorry about typo. Any other comment is welcome.

Comment: Now, I have this error : Error CS0122 'CounterBase._a' is inaccessible due to its protection level. If I replace by protected, I can't use readonly. Other idea?

Comment: fixed now with `public class` ? ( or move classA and classB as [nested classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) ) Maybe nested classes are closer to your initial question.

Comment: It's not possible to access private field in subclass. You need add a getter and use this getter in component. In the constructor, use field and don't declare variables. Can you improve your answer?

Comment: @Orwel, sorry about mistakes, I didn't test it. Now it is running on my laptop without issues. Be free to ask anything.

Comment: I have tested your code. It work perfectly. Thank for your helps.