# C# method from derived class as delegate in base constructor

Tags: c#, delegates, static

Why is the following C# not legal? Does there exist a proper workaround?

```
public class Base
{
    public Base(Func<double> func) { }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base(() => Method()) <-- compiler: Cannot access non-static method 'Method' in static context
    {
    }

    public double Method() { return 1.0; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's effectively referring to "this" within the arguments to the base constructor, which you can't do.

If your delegate really doesn't need access to `this` (which your sample doesn't) you can just make it static. You could also use a method group conversion to make it simpler:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base(Func<double> func)
    {
        double result = func();
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base(Method)
    {
    }

    public static double Method() { return 1.0; }
}
```

If you *do* need to use "this", you could:

- Make it a virtual method instead of calling a delegate
- Make it a static method which *takes* an appropriate instance, e.g.

  ```
  public class Base
  {
      public Base(Func<Base, double> func)
      {
          double result = func(this);
      }
  }

  public class Derived : Base
  {
      public Derived() : base(x => Method(x))
      {
      }

      private static double Method(Base b) 
      {
          // The documentation would state that the method would only be called
          // from Base using "this" as the first argument
          Derived d = (Derived) b;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875975/corner-case-in-using-lambdas-expression-in-base-constructor/1876263#1876263) answer, using `this` when calling the base constructor in this way is invalid. And indeed when I try it, I get the "Cannot use 'this' in member initializer" error (since C#4 I believe). Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Ah, I like passing the reference to the base class and then casting it up to the derived class. That wasn't immediately obvious to me. +1

Answer (score 1):

Basically you get the compiler error because you are referencing the instance-method `Method` without an instance of your class `Derived`. When calling `base`, the constructor has not yet finished and you don't have an instance of your class yet. If you made `Method` `static` it would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this is simply to defer the initialization of the delegate to the derived class:

```
public class Base {
   protected Func<double> DoubleFunc { get; set; }

   protected Base() {
      // defer initialization by not setting DoubleFunc
      // or another possibility is to set it to a dummy function:
      DoubleFunc = () => 0;
   }

   public Base(Func<double> func) {
      DoubleFunc = func;
   }
}

public class Derived : Base {
   public Derived() {
      DoubleFunc = Method;
   }

   public double Method() { return 1.0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making `Method()` static as the compiler indicates? The problem is that an instance of `Derived` isn't available until after the constructor has returned so you can't call an instance method on it.

Answer (score 0):

The "workaround" would be to make Method() a static method.

I can't explain the technical reasons why this does not work but essentially you're trying to call a method on an instance which does not yet exist. How could it possibly work?